# php.ini & SMTP= - how do you pass username & password

Tags: php, smtp, email

`My ISP` account requires that I send a username & password for outbound `SMTP` mail.

How do I get `PHP` to use this when executing `php.mail()?` The `php.ini` file only contains entries for the server `(SMTP= )` and `From: (sendmail_from= )`.

Comment: Simple. Use hMailServer. It was 5 minutes for me to set it up. See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34818989/1293492

Answer (score 40, accepted):

PHP `mail()` command does not support authentication. Your options:

1. [PHPMailer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer)- [Tutorial](http://phpmailer.codeworxtech.com/index.php?pg=tutorial#2)
2. [PEAR](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail) - [Tutorial](http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/et073006.htm)
3. Custom functions - See various solutions in the notes section: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mail.php

Comment: Worth noting that PHP `mail()` *does* support authentication if 
(a) sendmail is installed on the server and (b) authentication details are provided in the php.ini file. See answers below for details.

Comment: @JamesMcCormack, if PHP only supports authentication in these two conditions, how does PHPMailer work? I it is just PHP and it allows the definition of authentication details in code.

Comment: @hiphip James McCormack is referring to PHP `mail()`, not to PHPMailer

Comment: To make mail() support authentication, use hMailServer. It was 5 minutes for me to set it up. See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34818989/1293492

Answer (score 38):

I apply following details on php.ini file. its works fine.

```
SMTP = smtp.example.com
smtp_port = 25
username = info@example.com
password = yourmailpassord
sendmail_from = info@example.com
```

These details are same as on outlook settings.

Comment: Should it work using port 465 as well, if the SMTP server is using that port?

Comment: Ya. Any port you can specify.

Comment: Did not work for me on PHP 5.6.20: `Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 530 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM`

Comment: Doesn't work for me and haven't been able to find any documentation whatsoever that would indicate that username or password are valid php.ini directives

Comment: @wedstrom After enter this did you get any error while reboot apache?

Comment: Didn't worked for me as well. Used SendMail php package for this.

Answer (score 21):

Use [Fake sendmail for Windows](http://glob.com.au/sendmail/) to send mail.

1. Create a folder named `sendmail` in `C:\wamp\`.
2. Extract these 4 files in `sendmail` folder: `sendmail.exe`, `libeay32.dll`, `ssleay32.dll` and `sendmail.ini`.
3. Then configure `C:\wamp\sendmail\sendmail.ini`:

> ```
> smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
> smtp_port=465
> auth_username=user@gmail.com
> auth_password=your_password
> ```

4. The above will work against a Gmail account. And then configure php.ini:

   > sendmail_path = "C:\wamp\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t"
5. Now, restart Apache, and that is basically all you need to do.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Windows 10, WampServer 2.5, PHP 5.5.12.

Comment: Thanks!!! This worked for me. After like a week of trying to set up my own SMTP server I got it bc of your answer, thanks really <3

Comment: Use the latest [sendmail for Windows](https://github.com/sendmail-tls1-2/main) and follow the basic installation instructions, make sure to remove the `smtp` configuration from your `php.ini` file because that isn't really required if you already handle those values in your `sendmail.ini` file. Also I was only able to get it to work if I use `sendmail_path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\sendmail\sendmail.exe"` without the `-t` parameter. If anyone is curious, I was using IIS on Windows 10.

Answer (score 15):

PHP **does** have authentication on the mail-command for windows only!

The following is working for me on WAMPSERVER (windows, php 5.2.17)

php.ini

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
SMTP = mail.yourserver.com
smtp_port = 25
auth_username = smtp-username
auth_password = smtp-password
sendmail_from = you@yourserver.com
```

Comment: This is not working for me, PHP 5.3.8 on IIS 6. I had a look at the source code and it seems that smtp authentication is actually not implemented.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, I think you are using sendmail instead of smtp.

Comment: Agreed - on Windows, this answer only works if "Fake Sendmail" is installed on the server. It can be downloaded from: http://glob.com.au/sendmail/

Comment: Works on W8.1, PHP 5.2.17, using a remote SMTP server on port 587.

Comment: It doesn't work for me using port 465. Windows 10, WampServer 2.5, PHP 5.5.12.

Comment: Worked out of the box for me. No fake sendmail required. Windows 7 x64, XAMPP with PHP 5.5.27 (32 bit).

Comment: Did not work for me on PHP 5.6.20 with SMTP activated: `Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 530 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM`

Answer (score 11):

1. Install Postfix (Sendmail-compatible).
2. Edit `/etc/postfix/main.cf` to read:

```
#Relay config
relayhost = smtp.server.net
smtp_use_tls=yes
smtp_sasl_auth_enable=yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/cacert.pem
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
```

3. Create `/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd`, enter:

```
smtp.server.net username:password
```

4. Type # `/usr/sbin/postmap sasl_passwd`
5. Then run: `service postfix reload`

Now PHP will run mail as usual with the `sendmail -t -i` command and Postfix will intercept it and relay it to your SMTP server that you provided.

Answer (score 5):

I prefer the [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.codeworxtech.com/) tool as it doesn't require PEAR. But either way, you have a misunderstanding: you don't want a PHP-server-wide setting for the SMTP user and password. This should be a per-app (or per-page) setting. If you want to use the same account across different PHP pages, add it to some kind of settings.php file.

Comment: How to add username and password in  a php file. Can I use this for sending mail using PHP mail function through http://developer.postmarkapp.com/developer-smtp.html Postmark

Comment: Some other popular apps may depend on PHPMailer, like WordPress internally, which may in turn be configured to use the internal mail() function to send the actual email. Therefore, PHP-wide configuration would be preferred.

Answer (score 5):

After working all day on this, I finally found a solution. Here's how I send from Windows XP with WAMP.

1. Use Google's SMTP server. You probably need an account.
2. Download and install [Fake Sendmail](http://glob.com.au/sendmail/). I just downloaded it, unzipped it and put it in the WAMP folder.
3. Create a test PHP file. See below.

> ```
> <?php
>     $message = "test message body";
>     $result = mail('recipient@some-domain.com', 'message subject', $message);
>     echo "result: $result";
> ?>
> ```

4. Update your php.ini file and your sendmail.ini file (sendmail.ini is in the sendmail folder).
5. Check the error.log file in the sendmail folder that you just created if it doesn't work.

Reference:

- http://www.geekzone.co.nz/tonyhughes/599
- http://www.joshstauffer.com/send-test-emails-with-wampserver/

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Windows 10, WampServer 2.5, PHP 5.5.12.

Answer (score 1):

Use Mail::factory in the Mail PEAR package. [Example.](http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/et073006.htm)

Answer (score 1):

These answers are outdated and deprecated.
The actual best practice would be:

```
composer require phpmailer/phpmailer
```

As the next step, your sendmail.php file just requires the following:

```
# use namespace
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

# require php mailer
require_once "../vendor/autoload.php";

//PHPMailer Object
$mail = new PHPMailer;

//From email address and name
$mail->From = "from@yourdomain.com";
$mail->FromName = "Full Name";

//To address and name
$mail->addAddress("recepient1@example.com", "Recepient Name");
$mail->addAddress("recepient1@example.com"); //Recipient name is optional

//Address to which recipient will reply
$mail->addReplyTo("reply@yourdomain.com", "Reply");

//CC and BCC
$mail->addCC("cc@example.com");
$mail->addBCC("bcc@example.com");

//Send HTML or Plain Text email
$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = "Subject Text";
$mail->Body = "<i>Mail body in HTML</i>";
$mail->AltBody = "This is the plain text version of the email content";

if(!$mail->send()) 
{
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} 
else 
{
    echo "Message has been sent successfully";
}
```

This can be configured however you like.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install the latest [hMailServer](https://www.hmailserver.com/download). "Run hMailServer Administrator" in the last step.
2. Connect to "localhost".
3. "Add domain..."
4. Set "127.0.0.1." as the "Domain", click "Save".
5. "Settings" > "Protocols" > "SMTP" > "Delivery of e-mail"
6. Set "localhost" as the "Local host name", **provide your data in the "SMTP Relayer" section**, click "Save".
7. "Settings" > "Advanced" > "IP Ranges" > "My Computer"
8. Disable the "External to external e-mail addresses" checkbox in the "Require SMTP authentication" group.
9. If you have modified php.ini, rewrite these 3 values:

"SMTP = localhost",

"smtp_port = 25",

"**;** sendmail_path = ".

Credit: [How to configure WAMP (localhost) to send email using Gmail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600725/how-to-configure-wamp-localhost-to-send-email-using-gmail/16814318#16814318)

Comment: This works perfectly on Windows 10, using WampServer 2.5, with PHP 5.5.12.

Comment: Hi @Tamas
In SMTP Relayer I set up my credentials from AWS SES
host name, port, username and password.
But it is not working fine. Do you know if i should do something else ?