# How to configure WAMP (localhost) to send email using Gmail?

Tags: php, gmail, localhost, wamp

I want to use the mail() function from my localhost. I have WAMP installed and a Gmail account. I know that the SMTP for Gmail is smtp.gmail.com and the port is 465 ([more info from gmail](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=78799)).
What I need to configure in WAMP so I can use the mail() function?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Gmail servers use SMTP Authentication under SSL or TLS. I think that there is no way to use the `mail()` function under that circumstances, so you might want to check these alternatives:

- [PEAR::Mail](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail)
- [phpMailer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/)
- [Nette\Mail](https://github.com/nette/mail)

They all support SMTP auth under SSL.

You'll need to enable the `php_openssl` extension in your php.ini.

Additional Resources:

- [How to Send Email from a PHP Script Using SMTP Authentication](http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/et073006.htm) (using `PEAR::Mail`)
- [Send email using PHP with Gmail](http://deepakssn.blogspot.com/2006/06/gmail-php-send-email-using-php-with.html)  (using *phpMailer*)
- [Mailing](https://doc.nette.org/en/2.3/mailing) using `Nette\Mail`

Comment: Would you tell me exact location where to place 
$host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
$port = 465;

.?
Thanks

Answer (score 14):

I've answered that here: [(WAMP/XAMP) send Mail using SMTP localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830673/wamp-xamp-send-mail-using-smtp-localhost) (works not only GMAIL, but for others too).

Comment: I need to bookmark this instruction before memory leakage.

Comment: Followed those instructions, works perfect with hmailserver 5.6.4 and a gmail account. If you get an error message `530 SMTP authentication is required`, then you need to follow the last indication (the p.s.)

Answer (score 11):

If you open the php.ini file in wamp, you will find these two lines:

```
smtp_server
smtp_port
```

Add the server and port number for your host (you may need to contact them for details)

The following two lines don't exist:

```
auth_username
auth_password
```

So you will need to add them to be able to send mail from a server that requires authentication. So an example may be:

```
smtp_server = mail.example.com
smtp_port = 26
auth_username = example_username@example.com
auth_password = example_password
```

Comment: Not tested, but this is probably wrong. There are no such directives for PHP as stated above (except `smtp_port`). Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/21891895/3827190 as a reference.

Answer (score 3):

It's quite simple. (Adapt syntax for your convenience)

```
public $smtp = array(
    'transport' => 'Smtp',
    'from' => 'your_email@gmail.com',
    'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
    'port' => 465,
    'timeout' => 30,
    'username' => 'your_email@gmail.com',
    'password' => '*****'
)
```

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to PHPMailer, Pear's Mail and others you could use the [Zend's library](https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.mail.sending.html)

```
  $config = array('auth' => 'login',
                   'ssl' => 'ssl',
                   'port'=> 465,
                   'username' => 'XXXX@gmail.com',
                   'password' => 'XXXXXXX');

 $transport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp('smtp.gmail.com', $config);
 $mail = new Zend_Mail();
 $mail->setBodyText('This is the text of the mail.');
 $mail->setFrom('XXXX@gmail.com', 'Some Sender');
 $mail->addTo('kazifriend@gmail.com', 'Some Recipient');
 $mail->setSubject('TestSubj');
 $mail->send($transport);
```

That is my set up in localhost server and I can able to see incoming mail to my mail box.

Answer (score 2):

i know in XAMPP i can configure sendmail.ini to forward local email.
need to set

```
smtp_sever
smtp_port
auth_username
auth_password
```

this works when using my own server, not gmail so can't say for certain you'd have no problems

Answer (score 2):

use stunnel on your server, to send with gmail. google it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm positive it would require SMTP authentication credentials as well.

Answer (score 1):

[PEAR: Mail](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail) worked for me sending email messages from Gmail. Also, the instructions:  [How to Send Email from a PHP Script Using SMTP Authentication](http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/et073006.htm) (Using PEAR::Mail) helped greatly. Thanks, CMS!