# email is not being received from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, email

I am trying to create a php script that sends email to specified email id. Script runs successfully without any error but I am not receiving email from database. I am using this script for android app. After filling contact us form from app, when user clicks on SEND, all the details should be received in email. Surprisingly I am seeing the user's entry in database from PhpMyAdmin, however email is not being sent with the data.

I am using following code.

```
<?php
require('config.php');
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');

$type_of_occasion = trim($_REQUEST['type_occasion']);
$date = trim($_REQUEST['date']);
$content = trim($_REQUEST['content']);
$email = trim($_REQUEST['email']);

if(empty($type_of_occasion) || empty($date) || empty($content) || empty($email)){
echo json_encode(array('status'=>'error','message'=>'Please enter all fields[type,date,content,email of user]'));
exit();
}

$date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date));
$query = "INSERT INTO inquiry (email,type_of_occasion,date,content) VALUES ('$email','$type_of_occasion','$date','$content')";
$res = mysqli_query($con,$query);

if($res){
$to = 'abc@email.com';
$message = "Hi,<br>You have one inquiry with below information<br>Email : $email<br>Type Of Occassion : $type_of_occasion<br>Date : $date<br>Details : $content";
$subject = "You have one inquiry";

$header = "From: noreply@xyz.com\r\n"; 
$header.= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
$header.= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n"; 
$bool = mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);
if($bool){
echo json_encode(array('status'=>'success','message'=>'Inquiry submitted successfully'));
}else{
echo json_encode(array('status'=>'error','message'=>'Error in mail send'));
}

}else{
echo json_encode(array('status'=>'error','message'=>'Error in submitting inquiry'));
exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a local environnement make sure that your server is configured to be able to send mail, since many of them can't with default configuration, for example with WAMP you need to configure your SMTP server properly.

[How to send email from local wamp server using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7820225/how-to-send-email-from-local-wamp-server-using-php)

Comment: thanks for the quick response! Let me try that out.

Comment: Also note that this script was running perfectly fine till yesterday. This issue has occurred just recently! @Nirnae