# How use mail() function on localhost

Tags: php, localhost, sendmail, wampserver

I want to use my site mail testing in wamp server but server port error display.
so please suggest how i use mail() function on my localhost server.
thanks.

Comment: you got to have mail server running in your machine

Comment: unless you happen to have a mail server installed you will have to use an external one such as your isp or gmail. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600725/how-to-configure-wamp-localhost-to-send-email-using-gmail?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

if you are under WampServer:
configure your php.ini file with

```
SMTP = 127.0.0.1
smtp_port = 25
```

Comment: For use of this port & server.I found Mail() function not use using SMTP port 25 error.

Comment: may be port 25 is used by skype or other application