# Developing a site on localhost; how should I send emails

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, wamp

I am developing a site on my computer using wamp. When it is done the site will send a lot of emails and I will set up an email server along with wamp and figure that configuration out when that time comes. In the mean time I would like to know the method of minimum hassle for developing the site on local host.  Here are some criteria that I would like a solution to meet, and also some information about my setup.

I am using CodeIgniter and wamp.

I do not want to port forward as I am not always on the same network and I many of the networks I am on I do not have access to port forward anyway.

I would rather avoid installing some sort of email server on my computer IF that can be avoided.

Can I get some advice on best practice for developing a website that sends emails?

Comment: you can check "mailcatcher" out, it's useful during development stage.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to configure WAMP (localhost) to send email using Gmail?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600725/how-to-configure-wamp-localhost-to-send-email-using-gmail)

Answer (score 4):

Use [Mailgun API](http://www.mailgun.com/) to send emails. It is free(10K emails/month) for basic usage and testing purposes. Also have a look at [Mandrill](http://mandrill.com/), I haven't tried this yet. But it is from Mailchimp and looks promising. It is also have a free plan (12K emails/month).

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This is the way to go. Amazon SES is another option.  They have the benefit of scaling well, being ready for heavy traffic, and being much easier to use then an actual SMTP server.

Comment: Mandrill by Mailchimp; I wonder why Mailchimp users don't move to Mandrill(?) Mailchimp's prices are phenomenal compared to Mandrill; what gives? Oh, and +1 by the way, two good resources I wasn't aware of till now.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Mandrill is pretty much raw email sending. You'd have to manage your own lists, segmentation, email templates, analytics, sign-up forms, etc. that Mandrill handles for you.

Comment: @ceejayoz Thanks, I appreciate the added information.

Comment: Whoops, should've said "that Mailchimp handles for you" there. :-)

Comment: @ceejayoz Not a problem. I would've found out for myself eventually lol! cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can configure your CI site to use an SMTP server (gmail, etc).

Just use your personal email account, or create a new email account for the web site.  See http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/email.html for more info.