# How to send email from localhost WAMP Server to send email Gmail Hotmail or so forth?

Tags: php, email, localhost, wamp

I'm finding to proper information about how to **send email from localhost WAMP**. And how to get authorize to send email from particular authorize email address to send any other email address.

How to configure this whole step explain me details, I already visit here some Stack Overflow answer as well as blog post but all are very confusing and old dated so it's may be possible to not working. So i need Stack Overflow users help. Thank you.

Comment: you can't send email from your localhost. it requires smtp.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Configuring a working email client from `localhost` is quite a chore, I have spent hours of frustration attempting it. At last I have found this way to send mails (using WAMP, XAMPP, etc.):

### Install [hMailServer](http://www.hmailserver.com/)

Configure this hMailServer setting:

1. Open hMailServer Administrator.
2. Click the "Add domain ..." button to create a new domain.
3. Under the domain text field, enter your computer's localhost IP.

   - Example: 127.0.0.1 is your localhost IP.
4. Click the "Save" button.
5. Now go to Settings > Protocols > SMTP and select the "Delivery of Email" tab.
6. Find the localhost field enter "localhost".
7. Click the Save button.

Configure your Gmail account, perform following modification:

1. Go to Settings > Protocols > SMTP and select "Delivery of Email" tab.
2. Enter "smtp.gmail.com" in the Remote Host name field.
3. Enter "465" as the port number.
4. Check "Server requires authentication".
5. Enter your Google Mail address in the Username field.
6. Enter your Google Mail password in the password field.
7. Check mark "Use SSL"
8. Save all changes.

---

#### Optional

If you want to send email from another computer you need to allow deliveries from External to External accounts by following steps:

1. Go to Settings > Advanced > IP Ranges and double click on "My Computer" which 
       should have IP address of 127.0.0.1
2. Check the Allow Deliveries from External to External accounts Checkbox.
3. Save settings using Save button.

Comment: shall i know how to use this in php script... after configure

Comment: But remember, no decent real mail server will accept mail from you as you will look more like a spammer than a sensible quality mail server

Answer (score 10):

For me [Fake Sendmail](http://glob.com.au/sendmail/) works.

**What to do:**

1) Edit `C:\wamp\sendmail\sendmail.ini:`

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=465
auth_username=user@gmail.com
auth_password=your_password
```

2) Edit `php.ini` and set `sendmail_path`

```
sendmail_path = "C:\wamp\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t"
```

That's it. Now you can test a mail.

Answer (score 3):

Try using fake sendmail to send emails in a WAMP enviroment.

http://jesin.tk/using-sendmail-on-windows/

Comment: i need proper configuration step. i check this all URL

Comment: What do you mean. I think the link I provided you explains the steps needed.

Answer (score 2):

```
a) Open the "php.ini". For XAMPP,it is located in C:\XAMPP\php\php.ini. Find out if you are using WAMP or LAMP server. Note : Make a backup of php.ini file 

b) Search [mail function] in the php.ini file. 

You can find like below.
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25


; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
;sendmail_from = postmaster@localhost


Change the localhost to the smtp server name of your ISP. No need to change the smtp_port. Leave it as 25. Change sendmail_from from postmaster@localhost to your domain email address which will be used as from address.. 

So for me, it will become like this.
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
SMTP = smtp.planetghost.com
smtp_port = 25
; For Win32 only.
sendmail_from = info@planetghost.com
auth_username = example_username@example.com
auth_password = example_password


c) Restart the XAMPP or WAMP(apache server) so that changes will start working.

d) Now try to send the mail using the mail() function , 

mail("abc@gmail.com","Success","Great, Localhost Mail works");
```

[credit](http://planetghost.com/send-emails-localhost-xampp-wamp-php)

================================================================================

Another way

Gmail servers use SMTP Authentication under SSL. I think that there is no way to use the mail() function under that circumstances, so you might want to check these alternatives:

1. [PEAR: Mail](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail)
2. [phpMailer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/)

They both support SMTP auth under SSL.

Credit : [Check reference answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/600748/2419644)

Comment: i try this way to configure

Comment: do u mean you already tried ?

Comment: no, currently i follow this step to configure..

Comment: auth_username and auth_password are not exists you need to add in php.ini with their value

Answer (score 1):

**Here are the steps for send email from localhost by wamp server with Sendmail.**

1. First, you need to download Sendmail zip file [link](http://www.glob.com.au/sendmail/sendmail.zip)
2. Extract the zip file and put it on C:\wamp
3. Now, you need to edit **Sendmail.ini** on `C:\wamp\sendmail\sendmail.ini`

> ```
> smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com 
> smtp_port=465
> auth_username=user@gmail.com
> auth_password=your_password
> ```

4. Access your email account. Click the Gear Tool > Settings >
   Forwarding and POP/IMAP > IMAP access. Click "Enable IMAP", then
   save your changes
5. Run your WAMP Server. Enable ssl_module under Apache Module.
6. Next, enable php_openssl and php_sockets under PHP.
7. ** Now the important part open **php.ini** file on `"C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.ini"` and
   `"C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin\php.ini"` set **sendmail_path** **

> sendmail_path = "C:\wamp\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t"

8. Restart Wamp Server.

**It will surely be worked.**

Answer (score 0):

Here is the BESTEST way to send emails using PHPmailer library, this is the only method that works for me.

```
require_once 'mailer/class.phpmailer.php';
    $mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail->Port = 465; // or 587
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Username = "xxxxxx@gmail.com";
    $mail->Password = "xxxxxxx";
    $mail->SetFrom("xxxx@xxx.com");
    $mail->AddAddress($to);
    $logfile = dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/mail.log';
    try {
        $mail->Body = $message;
        $mail->Subject = $subject;


        file_put_contents($logfile, "Content: \n", FILE_APPEND);
        file_put_contents($logfile, $message . "\n\n", FILE_APPEND);

        if(!$mail->Send()) {
            echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        } else {
            echo "Email has been sent";
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        #print_r($e->getMessage());
        file_put_contents($logfile, "Error: \n", FILE_APPEND);
        file_put_contents($logfile, $e->getMessage() . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
        file_put_contents($logfile, $e->getTraceAsString() . "\n\n", FILE_APPEND);
    }
```

Comment: where can i download mailer and which mailer function you are using?

Comment: @151291 https://packagist.org/packages/phpmailer/phpmailer

Answer (score 0):

Without any SMTP server sending mail,use this code for sending mail....

```
click below for mail sending code
```

[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39524401/send-mail-successfully-and-shown-in-my-gmail-account/39525111#39525111)

listen guys first you can do this **less secure your gmail account** after send mail with your gmail account

**You can use this php.ini setting**

```
;smtp = smtp.gmail.com
;smtp-port = 25
;sendmail_from = my gmail is here
```

**And sendmail.ini settings**

```
smtp_server = smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port = 465
smtp_ssl = auto
auth_username = my gmail is here
auth_password = password
hostname = localhost

you can try this changes and i hope this code sent mail....
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a wamp setup that won't send emails, there is only a couple of things to do. 
1. find out what the smtp server name is for your isp. The gmail thing is most likely unnecessary complication
2. create a phpsetup.php file in your 'www' folder and edit  like this:

```
<?php
   phpinfo();
?>
```

this will give you a handle on what wamp is using.
3. search for the php.ini file. there may be serveral. The one you want is the one that effects the output of the file above.
4. find the smtp address in the most likely php.ini.
5. Type in your browser localhost/phpsetup.php and scroll down to smtp setting. it should say 'localhost'
6. edit the php.ini file smtp setting to the name of your ISPs smtp server.
check if it changes for you phpsetup.php. if it works your done, if not you are working the wrong file.

this issue should be on the Wordpress site but they are way too up-them-selves or trying to get clients.;)