# how to use mail() function on localhost with wampdevloper

Tags: php, email, localhost

I am using wampdevloper  for php .when i try to use  mail() function it shows me error

> Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "127.0.0.1" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\WampDeveloper\Websites\localhost\webroot\test1.php on line 9

what should i do for send email from localhost.

Comment: You can't. You need an SMTP with a FQDN (unless you set up your local host a relay, lots of work involved)

Comment: what is FQDN  from where i can get it.

Comment: should i use wampserver ,. for that i think  their is easy solution .

Comment: https://www.google.com/#q=fqdn

Comment: i don't want to buy a domain now . that's why i am trying it on localhost.

Comment: You can't just setup an email server. Most residential ISPs block the necessary ports, since hijacked computers often send email. You'll have to find an established mail server to send your email

Comment: their are many solution for wampserver. are they all fake.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22396721/how-to-send-email-from-localhost-wamp-server-to-send-email-gmail-hotmail-or-so-f

Comment: @nikhil all of the solutions for wampserver assume that you have a FQDN (which is required to host an SMTP server)

Comment: ok thanks.  however i will try those solution.