# Can't send mail from localhost even though i configured XAMPP

Tags: php, xampp

I can't send mail from localhost.

I am using Xampp v3.2.2 and I configured it based on the solution from this link: [How to configure XAMPP to send mail from localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965376/how-to-configure-xampp-to-send-mail-from-localhost)

I made sure to restart apache after the changes and so far I don't get any errors but the mail is not sent.

Thank you very much

Comment: Have you configured it with gmail or other?

Comment: Refer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22396721/how-to-send-email-from-localhost-wamp-server-to-send-email-gmail-hotmail-or-so-f)

Comment: I think you also need a mail server setup, if you don't want to do that you can use smtp, with a library like PHPMailer, and an email account to bounce it off of.  This should work for testing.