# How can we send email on our Local host in php?

Tags: php, localhost, email-validation

> Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS
>   command first. k9sm14645324wrk.88 - gsmtp in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\contact-form\form.php on line 34 Error sending email.

How can i send email on our Local host in PHP? 
i am beginner and i want to send email on our localhost in php. Kindly tell me how can i do this in php?

Comment: do you have a email server installed on your localhost?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send email from localhost WAMP Server to send email Gmail Hotmail or so forth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22396721/how-to-send-email-from-localhost-wamp-server-to-send-email-gmail-hotmail-or-so-f)

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://www.toolheap.com/test-mail-server-tool/ => mail server tool and update php.ini, remove semicolon ;smtp = localhost and put semicolon before sendmail_path

You may want to check the below thread.

[How to configure XAMPP to send mail from localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965376/how-to-configure-xampp-to-send-mail-from-localhost)