# Failed to send AUTH LOGIN command. Error: Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method

Tags: php, codeigniter, utf-8, outlook, smtp

I'm trying to send a email from Office 365 using PHP Code-Igniter. **But I got an error:**

> 220 MAXPR0101CA0041.outlook.office365.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service
>   ready at Tue, 26 Dec 2017 11:17:56 +0000
>
> hello: 250-MAXPR0101CA0041.outlook.office365.com Hello [115.96.169.89]
>
> 250-SIZE 157286400
>
> 250-PIPELINING
>
> 250-DSN
>
> 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
>
> 250-STARTTLS
>
> 250-8BITMIME
>
> 250-BINARYMIME
>
> 250-CHUNKING
>
> 250 SMTPUTF8
>
> Failed to send AUTH LOGIN command. Error:  504 5.7.4 Unrecognized
>   authentication type [MAXPR0101CA0041.INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]
>
> Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be
>   configured to send mail using this method.
>
> Date: Tue, 26 Dec 2017 12:17:56 +0100
>
> From:
>
> Return-Path:
>
> To: myemail@mydomain.com
>
> Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?Test=20Email?=
>
> Reply-To:
>
> User-Agent: CodeIgniter
>
> X-Sender: myemail@mydomain.com
>
> X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
>
> X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
>
> Message-ID: <5a422fe430795@mydomain.com>
>
> Mime-Version: 1.0
>
> Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="B_ALT_5a422fe4307e9"
>
> This is a multi-part message in MIME format. Your email application
>   may not support this format.
>
> --B_ALT_5a422fe4307e9 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
>
> SMTP sending test email, Done...
>
> --B_ALT_5a422fe4307e9 Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
>
> SMTP sending test email, Done...
>
> --B_ALT_5a422fe4307e9--

**Here is my Controller code:**

```
public function emailSend()
    {
        # code...
        /*
        Minimun test code for successful email sending over SMTP with Office 365
        Things to double-check: 
        - openssl php extension must be enabled in the server
        - host set to smtp.office365.com, not the old aliases
        - Port 587
        - newline configuration: explicit to "\r\n"
        */

        //In your Controller code:

        $this->load->library('email');        

        //$config = [
            $config['protocol']= 'smtp';
            $config['mailpath']= "/usr/lib/sendmail";
            $config['smtp_port']= 587;
            $config['smtp_timeout'] = '7';
            $config['smtp_host']= 'smtp-mail.outlook.com';
            $config['smtp_user']= 'myemail@mydomain.com';
            $config['smtp_pass']= '*********';
            $config['smtp_crypto']= 'STARTTLS';   
            $config['newline']= "\r\n"; //REQUIRED! Notice the double quotes!
            $config['crlf']= "\r\n";
            $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
        //];

        $this->email->initialize($config);

        $this->email->from('myemail@mydomain.com');        
        $this->email->to('myemail@mydomain.com');
        $this->email->subject('Test Email');
        $this->email->message('SMTP sending test email, Done...');

        $sent = $this->email->send();


        if ($sent) 
        {
            echo 'OK';

        } else {
            echo $this->email->print_debugger();
        }

    }
```

I had check lots of links and questions, but no success. I'm not getting what is exact error in code.

**Note:**
I'm tried

```
$config['smtp_port']= 465; 
$config['smtp_crypto']= 'TLS';
$config['smtp_crypto']= 'SSL';
```

Any kind of help is welcome, thanks in advance.

Comment: have you found any solution?? i have the same problem

Comment: @Sana Riaz:I've uploaded the script on live server, and it is running on server.

Comment: Okay, do you have any idea how can I work this around on wamp localhost??

Comment: @SanaRiaz refer this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22396721/how-to-send-email-from-localhost-wamp-server-to-send-email-gmail-hotmail-or-so-f

Comment: You can also try increasing smtp timeout `$config['smtp_timeout'] = '30'`

Answer (score 2):

had similar problem and my solution was changing,

```
$config['protocol'] = "smtp";
```

to:

```
$config['protocol'] = "sendmail";
```