# How to send mail using mail() function in PHP from localhost

Tags: php, email

I am using a mail() function to send mail in PHP from localhost but it is not working.

Sending mail from localhost is my primary concern. Please guide me a way to achieve the same.

Comment: Do you have a mailserver running on your host?

Comment: Nobody is going to help you with that arrogant attitude.

Comment: On localhost not possible

Comment: Usually most servers that comes with PHP have some form of mail server already set up. Could you please post some of the things you've tried and if you are getting any error messages?

Comment: (I've removed the shouting from the question - and if you can show what you have tried, that is most helpful).

Answer (score 0):

You won't have SMTP server installed by default so you can't send emails from localhost directly. Either you can set up SMTP server on local or use third party SMTP servers. Have a look at

> http://www.mittalpatel.co.in/php_send_mail_from_localhost_using_gmail_smtp

which gives you insight about how to send mail from localhost using third party SMTP server.

Here's the some of the method that might be help you :

> **Method 1** https://stackoverflow.com/a/16814318/2377343
>
> **Method 2**
>   http://thephpcode.blogspot.com/2009/03/setting-up-local-mail-smtp-pop3-imap.html
>
> **Method 3** 
>   http://blog.techwheels.net/send-email-from-localhost-wamp-server-using-sendmail/
>
> **Method  4** Configure wamp server to send email
>
> **Method 5**
>   http://roshanbh.com.np/2007/12/sending-e-mail-from-localhost-in-php-in-windows-environment.html

Comment: Thanks Hardy but what I can see here that we need to provide password as well and it can be sent only via gmail. What if I wanna make it universal like mail() function of PHP?

Comment: @DipikaAwasthi.. i am edited my answer hope it should be work

Answer (score 0):

It is configured to use localhost:25 for the mail server.

The error message says that it can't connect to localhost:25.

Therefore you have two options:

1. Install / Properly configure an SMTP server on localhost port 25
2. Change the configuration to point to some other SMTP server that you can connect to

Comment: Thanks Ahmed. Can you guide me through the configuration of php.ini file for archiving the same?