# Wamp icon turned orange after enabling apache ssl module, skype is not installed

Tags: php, apache, ssl, localhost, sendmail

I am trying to send a mail for mail verification from localhost and for that I followed step by step the video on this [link to send mail from localhost](http://www.kicklabz.com/2015/04/how-to-send-email-from-wampserver-localhost.html) with the help of [glob.com](http://glob.com.au/sendmail/)

I download the plug in and extracted as required. Followed steps (editing php.ini, sendmail.ini etc) till the enabling of apache ssl module (time stamp 7:00) after which my wamp icon didn't turned green because the apache service is not running. Tested the port 80 and its also not used by any other program. I repeated the video multiple times to see if did some thing wrong  and also tried things like restart all services, install service and checked error log but nothing useful could be found.
wamp ver 3.0.0 and apache 2.4.17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending many hours of useless research to fix this problem I finally decided to reverse changes and re-intalled my wamp. However, I couldn't give up what I was trying to do. Finally, I found simple and an easy way to send mail from local host using gmail.  installed hMailServer and followed only a few steps listed  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16814318/2377343)  I was surprised to see it was so easy.....
Thanks God it worked. :)

Answer (score 1):

SSL default port is 443, wamp also uses that port, hence the orange icon meaning not all services have started properly. Rebind SSL to a different, non-reserved port like 80, 8080, 443 etc and your problem should be fixed.

Comment: Some hint or link would be nice : )

Comment: You should edit the ssl.conf in your conf directory. this link might be useful
[Bind Apache to an IP Address for HTTPS](http://www.webdnstools.com/articles/plesk/apache_https_ip_address)

Answer (score 0):

If you install WAMPServer before you install the C++ Redistributable, it won't work even after you've installed it because you will miss a critical step in the installation where you tell Windows Firewall to let Apache run.

Uninstall WAMP by running the unins file in the wamp directory
Download and install the vbasic package here [http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8328]
Restart your computer
Install WAMP again. You should see a message with a purple feather telling you to allow access. Do so, and you should be all good

Comment: Before I followed the video instructions mentioned in the question my wamp was running fine. The problem arose when enabling apache ssl module. Did this solution fit in this situation too ?

Comment: Follow the following instructions to identify where the problem is.https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/apache-fix-common-ssl-errors.htm