# Sending email on ubuntu

Tags: php, sendmail

I don't know if this should go into Ubuntu or SO, so if the closure police arrive...I apologise. Anyho,

How can I setup php to send mail on ubuntu? I'm using pear_mime and only have a meagre googlemail account.

```
 sendmail_from has no value.
 sendmail_path is /usr/sbin/sendmail (-t -i)
 SMTP is localhost and stmp_post is 25
```

Happy Holidays.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/112190/php-ini-smtp-how-do-you-pass-username-password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the Mail and Net_SMTP packages in PEAR, you can use the solution here:

http://globalconstant.scnay.com/2009/11/06/sending-email-through-gmail-using-php/

That's how I got it to work with Gmail.

Answer (score 0):

Or, if this is a dev machine you can simply install a package like "postfix" which will then give you a full email sending environment.

Comment: I say Dev, because if you are sending emails for real there are a lot of anti-spam pit-falls you need to be very careful about. But if it's just dev machine and you don't mind rooting in spam folders to get your mail sometimes give it a go.