# Mail() not working, any ideas why?

Tags: php, email, function

Hi guys i am using the mail() from the contact form and for some reason it is not working.

The php coding i have setup is as follows:

```
            // sending email to sales@xxx.com
        $to      = "hello@xxx.com";
        $subject = 'Email From {$name} from your website';
        $message = "$name has contacted you from the website and says:

        $mcontent

        $name 's contact email address is: $email"; 

        $headers = $email . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: " . $email . "\r\n"; 
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 

        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) or die ("Failure");
        // end of sending mail

        returnheader("/xxx/email-sent");
```

i get no errors at all, it even goes to the success page when completed.

Any ideas why this would not work.

Comment: use exit; under mail() and see if you still get no errors.

Comment: [`error_reporting()`](http://il2.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Comment: @Jleagle the email is the email that is submitted in the contact form, as i say i have tested and no errors are submitted

Comment: So many duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+mail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have checked your code and it is working fine on my server , i am getting e-mail.
Here , it looks like some problem with your SMTP server settings.
There is nothing wrong with your PHP script.
You can find your solution here.
[php.ini & SMTP= - how do you pass username & password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112190/php-ini-smtp-how-do-you-pass-username-password)

Also in windows environment ,
http://www.ruhanirabin.com/php-sendmail-setup-with-smtp-iis-and-windows-servers/

Comment: Thank you, i am looking into phpmailer to send smtp direct.

Answer (score 1):

- If you are on WIndows, make sure you have an SMTP server in your
  php.ini
- If you are una Unix, make sure the MTA is running: If it is (at least partly) installed but not runnng, you will get exactly this effect

**Edit**

If your MTA is not running, and you start it, the mails sent with PHP will go out! They have beein queued, but not processed.

Comment: Depends on the OS - which one do you use?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably related to the mail setup. Do you have a mailserver running on the machine? Check sendmail / smtp_server settings in php.ini.

Comment: there is no smtp options within the php.ini file

Comment: Would be for win32, but seems like that is not the case then.

Answer (score 1):

`mail()` uses the `sendmail`, by default: `sendmail -t -i`

It returns `TRUE` if the mail has been accepted, not if it has been sent:

> **Return Values**
>
> Returns TRUE if the mail was successfully accepted for delivery, FALSE otherwise.
>
> It is important to note that just because the mail was accepted for delivery, it does NOT mean the mail will actually reach the intended destination.

I would suggest using http://swiftmailer.org/ with SMTP rather than `mail()`.

Comment: @Tim i cant seem to get the swiftmailer to work, as far as i can see it uses smtp sendmail anyway doesnt it? When setting it up, it just gives a blank screen when submitted contact details.

Answer (score 0):

You should use double quotes instead of single quotes in the variable `$subject`

```
$subject = "Email From {$name} from your website";
```

Answer (score 0):

The first line of `$headers` is invalid if `$email` is just an email address. Presumably you would want something like:

```
$headers = "Cc: " . $email . "\r\n";
```

or

```
$headers = "From: " . $email . "\r\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

The cause can be for example, you don't have setup a mail server, or configuration of firewall if you has it.