# How to set smtp username and password using ini_set

Tags: php, smtp

This is my script to send a html mail.But after executing this script, I did't get mail.I don't know how to set username and password using ini_set("SMTP","smtp.xyz.com");? Is their any simple way to set SMTP without using any external library files?.

```
$name=$_POST['name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$mobile=$_POST['mobile'];
$messege="Dear Webmaster,<br /> An user sent query.<br /> Query: <br/> ".$_POST['messege']."<br /><br /><br /> <b>User Contact Detail:</b><br />Name:".$name."<br/> Email:".$email."<br />Mobile:".$mobile;

$to = 'xyz@gmail.com';
$subject = 'xx';

$headers = "From: abc@xyz.com\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion() . "\r\n" .
"MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" .
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n" .
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n\r\n";

ini_set("SMTP","smtp.xyz.com");
ini_set("smtp_port","25");
ini_set("sendmail_from","abc@xyz.com");
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: See here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/112190/php-ini-smtp-how-do-you-pass-username-password

Comment: You can also consider using a library that has done the hard work of abstracting the intricacies of sending email away (http://swiftmailer.org/)

Comment: I am using XAMPP on Linux OS, so  below script will work ?      SMTP = mail.yourserver.com
smtp_port = 25
auth_username = smtp-username
auth_password = smtp-password
sendmail_from = you@yourserver.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you may read [in the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php#ini.smtp-port), the SMTP functionaliy for PHP is only available on Windows and it only has very basic functionality. If you need to use it on Linux and / or need username and password authentication, SMTPS, etc you will need to use libraries like [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/), [PHP Mailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/), etc. or you need to set up an external SMTP server on your own host like [Exim](http://exim.org/).

You should, however, not attempt to set up an SMTP server unless you are experienced in such matters, or you will make your server a nest for spammers in a matter of days.