# the wordpress registration form fails to send emails

Tags: wordpress, email

I have setup a wordpress site on godaddy account.
The registration form does not send emails to the users for passwords.

what is the problem in the site?

Comment: Let upload one sample static php mail code and cross check your SMTP working fine or not, are you getting other mails like comment, new registration etc...

Comment: I have uploaded a static email code to the server. It displays that email sent but I did not receive any email.

Comment: So the problem is not wordpress, ask your hosting provider that why mail is not working

Comment: sorry, the email was sent successfully and I receive the emails with the simple mail script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it looks like some problem with your SMTP server settings. There is
>   nothing wrong with your PHP script because its wordpress . You can
>   find your solution here.

[php.ini & SMTP= - how do you pass username & password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112190/php-ini-smtp-how-do-you-pass-username-password)

> Also in windows environment

http://www.ruhanirabin.com/php-sendmail-setup-with-smtp-iis-and-windows-servers/

> SMTP Settings for Go Daddy Email Accounts :-

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/smtp-settings-for-go-daddy-email-accounts

Comment: I have installed the wp-mail-smtp plugin. And from settings I select the PHP mail function to send email. But I recieve the error message "Could not instantiate mail function".

Comment: Have a look on this http://wordpress.org/support/topic/could-not-instantiate-mail-function and you need to install http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/smtp/faq/ plugin for this.

Comment: Yes But it did not work form me also. My site is hosted on godaddy account.

Comment: Did you try after installing above plugin ?

Comment: Did you setup all SMTP details in your wordpress ?

Comment: yes I have smtp host smtpout.secureserver.net. But when I try it the wordpress gives me the error of could not connect to smtp host.

Comment: thank a lot. I used the the smtp settings for go daddy account as described in your link and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider moving to a better host. Godaddy is a major domain seller and hosting provider, but most of their users are first timers who just want to pop-up a page. They don't care if you want to do something advanced as their support is only phone-based.

I suggest you to try a more professional hosting. I am using hostgator, arvixe, iweb, try one of these.