# No e-mail is send using mail function in PHP

Tags: php, email

I just need that when form is submitted  mail is send to recipient. My form submitted with Response code of 200k but mail is not Delivered. I have installed sendmail.

sendmail.php code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $to = "abc@gmail.com";
    $from = $_POST['email'];
     //data
    $msg = "NAME: "  .$_POST['name']    ."<br>\n";
    $msg .= "EMAIL: "  .$_POST['email']    ."<br>\n";
    $msg .= "WEBSITE: "  .$_POST['web']    ."<br>\n";
    $msg .= "COMMENTS: "  .$_POST['comments']    ."<br>\n";
    //Headers
    $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: <".$from. ">" ;
    mail ($to, $subject,$msg, $headers);
    echo "sent";
}
```

installed mail server in php.ini file:

```
 [mail function]
; Setup for Linux systems
 sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
sendmail_from = me@myserver.com
```

Comment: Have you searched with the `[php] mail email` keywords here? You'll get a plethora of questions exactly the same as you

Comment: yes sir i have googled used code above from there .

Comment: You may need to configurate the email settings.

Comment: i have configure mail in php.ini using help of link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/112190/php-ini-smtp-how-do-you-pass-username-password

Answer (score 2):

```
mail ($to, $subject,$msg, $headers);
echo "sent";
```

instead of this ,first check if the mail is sent

```
$mail=mail ($to, $subject,$msg, $headers);
if($mail){
  echo "sent";
}else{
  echo "failed."; 
}
```

By this actually u can know whether your mail function in working or not

if it is not working.the problem can be with SMTP settings in your localhost

enable errors in php if not enabled using

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
```

Comment: a i have tried like this but  echo "sent"; what wrong in code

Comment: Ok if your mail function is returning true then sendmail is not properly configured on your server.

Comment: what should do next to debug problem please suggest me.

Comment: sudo apt-get install sendmail i have install send mail ist succesfully updated

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked mail settings in you **php.ini** ?

[PHP Runtime Configuration](http://www.php.net//manual/en/mail.configuration.php)

If you don't have access to the PHP settings you can use [PHP Mailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) to deliver emails with your own parameters

Comment: i have used configuration of mail in php .ini using url:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/112190/php-ini-smtp-how-do-you-pass-username-password

Comment: i have used linux cmd :sudo sendmailconfig

Comment: i have installed so plaese tell where im wrong i have done all trouble shooting then i have post my query on stackoverflow