# send mails with php using "sendmail"?

Tags: php, email, smtp, sendmail, ini

I'm done searching for tutorials of how to configure my Linux system to send e-mails via PHP. I hope you could help me..

So I have a valid webserver for a private website running on a Linux system. Now I want to send e-mails with a PHP-script over my SMTP email-account that came along with my domain.

I know I need some kind of mail transfer agent as referred in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112190/php-ini-smtp-how-do-you-pass-username-password). That's why I've already installed the package "sendmail". Moreover I need to edit the php.ini by adding some authentication entries. Because I'd like to give myself later the opportunity to send from multiple mail server for other projects, I would like to set my php.ini temporary by using ini_set() at the top of my config.php.

```
ini_set("SMTP", "smtp.mydomainhoster.com");
ini_set("sendmail_from", "me@mydomain.com");
ini_set("port", "465");
ini_set("auth_username", "me@mydomain.com");
ini_set("auth_password", "mypassword");
```

But surprise: s*** does not work. After a long time of page loading I get a positive result from mail()-call but the sent E-mail never arrived.

```
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

What have I done wrong? Is it the configuration?

Thank you so much for your help! I appreciate that!!

Comment: Hey, if there isn't a specific reason for using vanilla PHP in order to achieve your goal, I suggest you use some sort of service or package to do this.
[Here](https://packagist.org/packages/swiftmailer/swiftmailer) is an example of a good package you can use. If you don't know how to use Composer, the documentation and installation can be found [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md)