# Bad conection between contact html and mail php

Tags: php, css, html, email

CSS y PHP of my contact-form. 
The page works perfectly but I'm trying to send an email and the button of send doesn't work. In the image you can see that when I try to send an email the button stays white. At the same time the button Clear works perfect! I attach my code

CONTACT.HTML

```
<form action="mail.php" method="POST" class="contact-form">

    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" class="required">

    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email address" class="contact-form-email required">

    <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" class="contact-form-subject">

    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message" class="required" rows="7"></textarea>

    <div class="response-message"></div>

    <button class="border-button" type="reset" id="reset" name="reset">Limpiar</button>
    <button class="border-button" type="submit" id="submit" name="submit">Enviar</button>
```

MAIL.PHP

```
<?php $name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "sa*********@*******.com";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!";
?>
```

Comment: Sorry, it's unclear what you are asking. What is the clue between your code snippets? What exactly does not work?

Answer (score 1):

`mail` function doesn't work on local server and also you need to set SMTP configuration in PHP to send mail.

Comment: How can I do SMTP configuration in PHP?

Comment: @SalvaCastro in `php.ini` file you'll need to set smtp host & port

Comment: I have my php.ini but I don't found where edit it.

Comment: @SalvaCastro there will be 2 fields `SMTP=` & `SENDMAIL_FROM=` , if you know these, fill them or you can look at this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/112190/4614728)

Answer (score 0):

Are you placing your form inside the form tag?

```
<form action="mail.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" class="required">

<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email address" class="contact-form-email required">

<input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" class="contact-form-subject">

<textarea name="message" placeholder="Message" class="required" rows="7"></textarea>

<div class="response-message"></div>

<button class="border-button" type="reset" id="reset" name="reset">Limpiar</button>
<button class="border-button" type="submit" id="submit" name="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: The form tag is present; it's just not showing due to Markdown. I'm editing the question now to show it.

Comment: Try changing the form method to get, and see if the button fetches the values in the URL, if it does, your form functions well. If it does not, there's something wrong with your form.

Comment: I wasn't the original poster; you'll probably need to comment on the original question to notify them.

Comment: @zuif there&#39;s issue about any HTML structuring here. Bad connection requestion happens for mail when SMTP isn&#39;t configured.