# Postfix - Cannot send mail from mail() php function

Tags: php, email, postfix-mta

I have simple postfix + dovecot configuration and everything works fine when i use Outlook (SMTP AUTH + IMAP ). The problem is when i try to send email via mail() function on localhost. The Recipient receive:

```
Diagnostic-Code:    smtp; 575 email@email sender requires authentication
```

My configuration file is as follow:

```
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
mynetworks_style = host
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/README_FILES
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated reject_unauth_destination
myorigin = domain.bg


smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain/privkey.pem

smtp_use_tls = yes
fallback_relay = 
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
```

and master.cf

```
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
# -o smtpd_tls_security_level=may
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
smtps     inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php.ini & SMTP= - how do you pass username & password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112190/php-ini-smtp-how-do-you-pass-username-password)