# Send php smtp email with mail()

Tags: php, email

I try to send email with a SMTP server. Is it possible to send message with mail() function? Or must i to use PHPMailer or Pear?

```
$to = "somebody@example.com";
$subject = "My subject";
$txt = "Hello world!";
$headers = "From: webmaster@example.com" . "\r\n" .
"CC: somebodyelse@example.com";
mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
```

Is it possible like:

```
$headers .= "Host: myhost.example.com\r\n";
$headers .= "User: myusername\r\n";
$headers .= "Password: mypassword\r\n";
```

? I'm looking for possible simple versions.

Comment: Do you have a mail server installed

Comment: Are you on a Windows or *nix server?

Comment: localhost iw windows and remote server is linux.

Comment: Windows does not come with a Mail Server, so you might be better using something like `phpMailer`

Comment: Yes, it is possible to send email with `mail()`. Are you having problems with this code? If so, what exactly is the problem you are seeing?

Comment: No working examples i found. This is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you can specify a server to use for SMTP in php.ini, but not on *nix where sendmail or something sendmail-compliant is expected to be found

What you can do on a *nix system is set up `postfix`, `Exim`, or some other smtpd to use as a authenticated relay to send mail via some other SMTP server.

But then this is rapidly heading towards `unix.stackexchange.com` or perhaps `superuser` or `serverfault`

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to sent emails through a SMTP server that requires authentication ? If so, you can't use the native mail() function :
[php.ini & SMTP= - how do you pass username & password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112190/php-ini-smtp-how-do-you-pass-username-password)

Answer (score 0):

Plenty of working examples in the [PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

e.g.

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = array(
    'From' => 'webmaster@example.com',
    'Reply-To' => 'webmaster@example.com',
    'X-Mailer' => 'PHP/' . phpversion()
);

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

To improve deliverability you may wish to set the 'Envelope From' address by passing the -f parameter to sendmail as follows:

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, '-f webmaster@example.com');
```

You should also check that an SPF record is setup on your domain allowing the web server IP address to send mail on behalf of the domain.