# What should I set my php.ini file configuration to, to activate the mail() function and use gmail as an smtp server?

Tags: php, email

I've been stuck on this one for quite a few days as I barely edit the `php.ini` file. I know that I need to specify the Gmail account, password, and SMTP server (smtp.gmail.com) but I don't know how or where to specify. I'm running this on localhost inside a Linux Ubuntu 18.04 Virtual Machine.
I've tried editing the `php.ini` file but I don't know how to use it.

**Note:** I am not interested in using third-party software such as PHPMailer (apart Sendmail as that is required to operate the mail() function in PHP)

Thank you in advance, 
Fed

Comment: "I am not interested in using third-party software such as PHPMailer", why is that? Libraries make things easier, lookup for example on how to send attachments

Comment: what os are you using?

Comment: this may help you [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-gmail-or-yahoo-with-php-mail-function)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php.ini & SMTP= - how do you pass username & password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112190/php-ini-smtp-how-do-you-pass-username-password)