# PHP mail function error Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM

Tags: php

My php.ini settings:

```
SMTP = smtp.office365.com
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 587

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = test@test.com
auth_username = test@test.com
auth_password = test123455@
smtp_ssl=tls
```

and I send mail using mail function:

```
//proceed with PHP email.
    $headers = 'From: '. $user_email .'' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: '.$user_email.'' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    $send_mail = mail($to_email, $subject, $message_body, $headers);
```

But I get error:

> PHP Warning:  mail(): SMTP server response: 530 5.7.57 SMTP; Client
>   was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM
>   [LO2P265CA0170.GBRP265.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM] in D:\Company
>   Website\abc\assets\php\mailer.php on line 44

Comment: Does this answer your question? [php.ini & SMTP= - how do you pass username & password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112190/php-ini-smtp-how-do-you-pass-username-password)